# Retagging counting as a significant question edit

Tags: discussion

When someone upvotes or downvotes, that vote eventually gets locked, and can not be reverted until that question is edited, changing the content of the question and allowing for re-assessment of votes. What I've noticed though, is that a retag of a question allows that vote to be changed, and that doesn't make sense to me. I don't think a retag constitutes enough of a change to allow for a new vote decision. If someone wanted to be vengeful and take away a previous vote, all they would need to do is to add a meaningless extra tag, or remove one and they would be able to alter their vote. I don't think it should work that way. Thoughts?

Comment: Cool.  I've got to remember that one :)

Comment: Even if this is changed, the way review's working out, they could just suggest a terrible edit and wait for it to be approved...

Comment: @AakashM This is true. I guess it's more of a question of whether they should change the way editing works, or to trust the community not to do things like this. I have seen it happen around the site a few times though.